# jq, recursive descent, finding substring in value of any subkey

Tags: jq

How can I change .a? to "any key"?  Like I wish I could put * instead of a.

```
'[[{"a":"hi there"}]]' | jq '..|select(.a?|contains("hi"))'

{
  "a": "hi there"
}
```

Or this nested object input?

```
'[[{"a":"hi there","b":{"c":"hi again"}}]]' | jq '..|select(.a?|contains("hi"))'

{
  "a": "hi there",
  "b": {
    "c": "hi again"
  }
}
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) and string ("hi") cannot have their containment checked
```

Comment: @pmf "array and string cannot have their containment checked".  Pipe to objects first?

Comment: What is your input JSON?

Comment: @0stone0 I pipe the input to jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all strings containing the substring "hi":

```bash
jq '..|select(contains("hi")?)'
```

```json
"hi there"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/q2zmDUqiWMK)

Note: Use the `-r` option to get raw strings instead of JSON strings.

---

To get all objects with at least one field containing the substring "hi":

```bash
jq '..|objects|select(any(contains("hi")?))'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gTXxGIj1OPK)

To get all objects as many times as it has fields containing the substring "hi":

```bash
jq '..|objects|select(.[]|contains("hi")?)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/G7m9ZWXXaRO)

Given your example, both cases evaluate to

```json
{
  "a": "hi there"
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could put a question mark there.

Comment: @js2010 The `?` is just shorthand for a `try` clause, so it works after any expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `..` will also encounter the strings so I'd use an `if/else` to only catch the `type == "object"` and then loop over those values and `select()` those who `contains("hi")`:

```
.. | if type == "object" then select(.[] | contains("hi")) else empty end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.. | objects|with_entries(select(.value|strings|test("hi")))
```

produces the output shown as wanted in the Q:

```
{ "a": "hi there" }
```

Comment: How about with nested objects?  `[[{"a":"hi there","b":{"c":"hi again"}}]]`  It says "object cannot be matched, as it is not a string"

Comment: Added `strings` to cover such cases.